# How to see logs of commit in tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I see the logs of commits in tortoise svn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just follow these simple steps

> Open Windows Explorer =>> Right Click on the Folder =>> Go to Tortoise Svn =>> Show Logs

Now, in open window you can see the commits and files are showed below the commit block.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above method you can also check the log messages using the Command Prompt.

You can follow the below steps

1. Open run utility by pressing WindowsKey+R and enter "cmd" to run the Command Prompt
2. Change the directory to your Project of which you want to see the log messages
3. Enter the following command

   **svn log**

This will print the log messages.